# mac M2（arm64）ubuntu dpkg --add-architecture i386

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, 32-bit

I'm on my ubuntu virtual machine on my mac with M2 arm64 architecture chip
Executing the ubuntu `dpkg --add-architecture i386`command doesn't give me any response

Comment: You'll need to be running *amd64* to add the 32-bit version being *i386*.  Since you're running *arm64* you could add the 32-bit version of ARM which is *armhf* but that likely won't help you if you want 32-bit x86 (i386) as its a different CPU

Answer (score 4):

ARM and x86 (which includes i386 and amd64) are different CPU architectures which are not compatible. Which means that software which is compiled for ARM will not natively run on x86 and vice versa. Thus, the command `dpkg --add-architecture i386` is not going to work on a computer like a Mac with an M1, M2 or M3 CPU.

Comment: Okay，thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running *arm64*, the 32-bit version for your machine/architecture is *armhf*.

If you're wanting to use *i386* you'll need to be using a x86 CPU which means *amd64* (*as per prior answer by @noisefloor*)

*armhf* won't help you run packages built for *i386* though.